# Extract association list, with assoc type, keys and class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to get the list of associations defined for a model.

Something like:

```
class AuthorModel
  has_many :pages, :class_name => PageModel
end

class PageModel
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => AuthorModel
end
```

`AuthorModel` assocs extracted:

```
[ :has_many, :pages, PageModel, [:id, :author_id] ]
```

`PageModel` assocs extracted:

```
[ :belongs_to, :author, AuthorModel, [:author_id, :id] ]
```

Also need `many-to-many` assocs extracted.

Iterated through model methods and did not found any method that could help me doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get an array of all associated objects:

`AuthorModel.reflect_on_all_associations`